# Determinar conteúdo para preencher UITableView com base em uma tag de UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c

Vou explicar o cenário para ficar o mais claro possível para entenderem a questão:
 Na tela principal do meu app eu tenho 4 `UIButton` e cada um deles abrirá uma tela diferente contendo cada uma sua própria `UITableVIew` e respectivo conteúdo.

Os botões são os seguintes:

Botão Restaurantes -> Irá abrir uma `UITableView` com um restaurante diferente em cada célula.
Botão Lojas -> Irá abrir uma `UITableView` com uma loja para cada célula.
Botão Lugares -> Irá abrir uma `UITableView` com lugares distintos em cada célula.
Botão Hoteis -> Irá abrir uma `UITableView` com um determinado hotel em cada célula.

Com este cenário, eu precisaria criar uma `UIViewController` para cada tela e sua respectiva `UITableView`. Oque acaba "poluíndo" o código e a tela do Storyboard.

Gostaria de saber um modo de utilizar somente uma única tela para exibir (com `UITableView` implementada) para exibir esses conteúdos separadamente, de acordo com o botão escolhido, já que o layout de exibição irá seguir o mesmo padrão. A solução que pensei seria utilizando a propriedade `tag` de `UIButton` para distinguir os botões e carregar o conteúdo adequado.

No caso oque desejo saber é: Como mostrar conteúdo diferentes usando a mesma `UITableView`, distinguindo o conteúdo a ser mostrado através do botão selecionado?

Qualquer dúvida sobre a questão basta deixar um comentário que poderei explicar novamente caso seja necessário.

Comment: Suas views estão sendo feitas com `storyboard` ou `xib`?

Comment: Estou usando Storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem como você disse, não precisa mesmo ter vários *controllers* para cada conteúdo diferente. Vamos supor que você tenha estes botões:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *btnRestaurantes;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *btnLojas;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *btnLugares;
```

Estes mesmo botões respondem a uma única ação:

```
- (IBAction)abrirConteudo:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"abrirConteudo" sender:sender];
}
```

Criei também um `enum` para cada tipo:

```
enum tipos {
    T_RESTAURANTES = 0,
    T_LOJAS,
    T_LUGARES
};
```

E ao preparar a `segue` do seu *storyboard*:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"abrirConteudo"]) {
        ViewConteudoController *viewConteudo = [segue destinationViewController];

        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

        if ([button isEqual:[self btnRestaurantes]]) {
            [viewConteudo setTipoConteudo:T_RESTAURANTES];
        } else if ([button isEqual:[self btnLojas]]) {
            [viewConteudo setTipoConteudo:T_LOJAS];
        } else if ([button isEqual:[self btnLugares]]) {
            [viewConteudo setTipoConteudo:T_LUGARES];
        }
    }
}
```

Pronto, no seu destino, que aqui eu chamei de `ViewConteudoController`, a variável `tipoConteudo` recebe um destes valores e a partir dele você decide o que exibir no conteúdo da sua tabela.

Acredito que isto também responda sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33526/4337).

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Paulo-Rodrigues!!

 Vou testar e te falo como ficou!

Comment: quando vc criou o enum, vc setou 0 para T_RESTAURANTES, mas os outros? Devem seguir a ordem crescente? 1, 2... ?

Comment: Na verdade nem precisava, foi só um exemplo, pois definindo o primeiro os próximos elementos serão incrementados. Se o primeiro fosse 5, os demais seriam 6, 7, 8 etc.

Comment: Paulo vc usa skype? me add la se puder falar: tiagofly@outlook.com