# Como a UIViewController atual pode saber qual botão a "Chamou"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Estou com uma dúvida e o cenário da questão é o seguinte:

Estou na tela principal da minha app e possuo 2 botões (`UIButton`), cada uma leva para uma outra tela.

Depois de o usuário escolher um botão e surgir a nova tela, no caso um novo `UIViewController`, a nova tela atual, que é outra `UIViewController`, saberia qual botão da tela anterior fez a chamada? Ou seja, há como saber qual dos dois botões fez o `push` ou `modal` `transiction`... agora no Xcode 6 é chamado de `show`?

Acredito que usando `UINavigationController` possa ter um modo de saber, mas alguém sabe dizer ao certo como pode ser feito isso?

Caso a pergunta tenha ficado confusa ou complexa basta avisar que posso tentar explicar de outro modo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [@PauloRodrigues](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4337/paulo-rodrigues) me ajudou muito com sua resposta para [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33520/determinar-conte%C3%BAdo-para-preencher-uitableview-com-base-em-uma-tag-de-uibutton/33549?noredirect=1#comment64240_33549/), e ainda respondeu esta. Vou deixar o link para quem estiver com o mesmo problema.

Link para Resposta: [Determinar conteúdo para preencher UITableView com base em uma tag de UIButton](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33520/determinar-conte%C3%BAdo-para-preencher-uitableview-com-base-em-uma-tag-de-uibutton)